# how would I calculate time based off decimal value

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

Ok, so I have been given tasks to do at work with time limits that are set in decimal values (I.E. Time to complete 0.064). Basing this of an 8 hour day I know how to convert this into a time format (I.E. 0h 30m) but how would I show this in percentages where the 8 hour day would be 100% and the time of task would be deducted from 100%? So if the task took 0.5, the percent would read 50% etc etc?

Working in Excel Sheet.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your original data? What's desired output? What you've tried? What about setting number format to percentage?

Comment: Original Data...
Number In B2: 0.064
Number In C2: =SUM(B2*8) this gives me a Number of 0.51
Time In D2: =C2/24 This gives me a Time of 00:30

How do I make the above a percentage where 100% is 8 hours and I deduct the 30 mins?

Just not sure of the format for the percentage cell... 

100% = 8hours - D2

Comment: Please incorporate this data into your question with an [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1539376/edit) and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you provided it's hard to be sure what you are looking for, but I assumed this for now:

[image]

And these are the formulas:

```
|   | A                    | B                                         | C                                  | D                     |
|---|----------------------|-------------------------------------------|------------------------------------|-----------------------|
| 1 | workday              | 8                                         | hours                              |                       |
| 2 |                      |                                           |                                    |                       |
| 3 |                      |                                           |                                    |                       |
| 4 | task                 | time available for task (fraction of day) | time available for task (hh:mm:ss) | remaining workday (%) |
| 5 | Read superuser help  | 0.1                                       | =B5*$B$1/1440                      | =1-B5                 |
| 6 | Show what I've tried | 0.2                                       | =B6*$B$1/1440                      | =D5-B6                |
| 7 | Work                 | 0.4                                       | =B7*$B$1/1440                      | =D6-B7                |
| 8 | Break                | 0.3                                       | =B8*$B$1/1440                      | =D7-B8                |
```

Column `C` is formatted as time, column `D` is formatted as a percentage.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is very close (sorry for my lack of explanation, I'm very very new to excel, like 2 days)

The only thing that's not quite right is, the  'time to complete' , the maximum value I can have is 1, this is how they are showing 8 hours. so essentially in Time to Complete, 8 hours is equal to 1.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: @PaulStarkey I've edited my answer.

Comment: That works a treat, thank you so much.